# OnClick not getting called even after OnClientClick returns true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

On click of "Confirm", the "btnSubmit_Click" does not get call in the codebehind. ClosePopup gets called on OnClientClick and  returns true, which should postback and call submit on the server side. Any ideas why it's not working?

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlId="btnCopyShip" 
    PopupControlID="ModalPanel" BackgroundCssClass="ui-widget-overlay"
    CancelControlID="btnCancel" behaviorid="modalwithinput"
    OnCancelScript="ClearUI();"/>

<asp:Panel ID="ModalPanel" runat="server" style="background-color:White; width:320px; padding:0px 10px 10px 10px; border:1px Black; display: none;height:100px" cssClass="shadow">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPnlNewShip" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <fieldset style="width:300px;">
        <legend style="font-weight:bold;font-size: medium">Copy Ship</legend>
        <label for="lblShip" style="padding-left: 0px" >Ship: </label>

        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlNewShips" style="width:150px">
        </asp:DropDownList><%-- ValidationGroup="popup"--%>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="popupRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="ddlNewShips" Display="None"
            ErrorMessage="Required Field" SetFocusOnError="True"
            InitialValue="0">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <%--ValidationGroup="popup"--%>

        <%--<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="server"
                targetcontrolid="popupRequiredFieldValidator"
                id="popupValidatorCalloutExtender"
                behaviorid="ddlValidator" enabled="True">
            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>--%>
    </fieldset>

    <br /><br />

    <span style="float: right"> 
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  OnClientClick="return ClosePopup()"/>  
    </span>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>

function ClosePopup()
{
    if (IsValid())
    {
        ClearUI();
        $find('modalwithinput').hide();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like thats an ASP question instead of javascript, am i right? Possibly add ASP to your tags could help

Comment: good point. thanks. added the asp.net tag.